# Umbraco multi-site 404 page not working

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am on Umbraco version 7.5.1, asp.net 4.6.1. 
I have one Umbraco application hosting two web sites (one anonymous and the other secure using Forms). 
I have specified this in the UmbracoSettings.Config but its good for the entire site

```
 <error404>//PageNotFound[1]</error404>
```

Is there a way to instruct Umbraco to use the 404 anonymous Doc type for anonymous site and use the secure 404 document type for the secure site?

Comment: Check out this forum post: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/7807-404-with-multiple-sites

Answer (score 0):

If the two websites are on different language then you can use this approach here https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/#errors

If you don´t have different languages on the site, then you could perhaps look at this package https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/umbraco-page-not-found-manager/ where you can set the 404 page from the context menu.

note:  the umbraco-page-not-found-manager application only works for users that are member of userType Alias of admin.  So you may have to download the code, revise it to your custom security needs.